# Loss of precision with gaussian elimination

Tags: android, double, resolution, precision, gaussian

Guys

I'm developping an app from structure analysis in engineering and at some point I have to solve a system of equations. For that, I'm using a simple gaussian elimination method that I put together quite quickly. Problem is, since I'm dealing with a lot of fractions, sort of big and small numbers, and the matrices are relatively big (300x300 is not uncommon), there's a huge loss of accuracy in the results: there are some cases when the loss reaches the second decimal algarism. Do you guys have some insight on that? Do I have to use BigDecimal or something similar?

Ps.: I'm using matrices of doubles.

Comment: Are you using pivoting?

Comment: Yes. I actually am implementing matrices of BigDecimals to get a better precision. I'm just worried that it might make the app too slow to run

Comment: You may be better off working on the numerical stability of your code. I've seen systems of thousands of linear equations solved with better accuracy than you report, using double.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest testing the solver from the [Java Linpack](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/linpackjava/) with your data. If it gets accurate results the problem is in your current implementation. If not, the issue is your data and you may need e.g. BigDecimal with more than 16 significant digits.